# Помогите написать Alert запрос на авторизацию

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку вход должно появиться окно с авторизацией(логин,пароль)
Помогите написать или скажите в каком русле это искать...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=ru

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже писал [@woesss](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11515/woesss) можно использовать либо штатные способы либо я бы предложил использовать собственный диалог со своей разметкой. Суть этого способа в том что вы создаете сначала файл разметки в каталоге `/layouts` например так:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type Your Message : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginetxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordetxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

и дальше уже создаете диалоговое окно со своей разметкой:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View myView= li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(myView);

final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

alertDialogBuilder
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
            }
    });
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

и вы сможете настроить свою разметку так как вам нужно. Здесь можно так же добавить и другие элементы для управления диалоговым окном. Вот есть [статья_1](http://learn-android.ru/news/realizacija_vvoda_teksta_v_alert_dialog/2015-05-14-106.html) и [статья_2](https://mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/) как это можно сделать, может так будет понятнее. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=ru#CustomLayout) документация для создания диалогового окна со своим макетом. А [вот](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=ru#PassingEvents) как обработать действия в диалоговом окне в основной активности.